# Jquery script reveals the hidden div very slowly-- performance issue

Tags: jquery, html, performance, optimization, toggle

I have a list of 6 items, and each one on click reveals a div that runs 100% wide under the row of list items. The code works, but the div opens very slowly and kind of choppy. Is there anything I can do to help it run more smoothly?

My HTML is set up as such:

```
 <ul>           
    <li><a class="artist-logo" href="#artist-1"><img src="images/looka-black-circle.png"></a></li>
    <div id="artist-1" class="artist-box">
    </div>
    <li><a class="artist-logo" href="#artist-2"><img src="images/looka-black-circle.png"></a></li>
    <div id="artist-2" class="artist-box">
    </div>
    <li><a class="artist-logo" href="#artist-3"><img src="images/looka-black-circle.png"></a></li>
    <div id="artist-3" class="artist-box">
    </div>
 </ul>
```

Here is my jscript:

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
 $(".artist-box").hide();
$(".artist-logo").click(function(e) {
e.preventDefault();
// get the clicked element
var clicked = $(this);

// get the selected element
var taggedWithSelect = $('.selected-artist');  
// get the corresponding divs
var clickPartner = $(clicked.attr('href'));
var selectPartner = $(taggedWithSelect.attr('href'));
var notClicked = $('.artist-logo').not(clicked);


        // we either want to close this one or open this one and close any others
        // if this one is open, it should be tagged with select
if( clicked.hasClass('selected-artist') ) {
    clicked.removeClass('selected-artist');
    notClicked.removeClass('blur-logo');
} else {                
  clicked.addClass('selected-artist');
  taggedWithSelect.removeClass('selected-artist');
  selectPartner.slideToggle();
  notClicked.addClass('blur-logo');
  clicked.removeClass('blur-logo');
}

clickPartner.slideToggle();

});

});
```

Comment: Can you try changing `clickPartner.slideToggle();` to `clickPartner.slideToggle(200);`? This will speed up the animation which *could* potentially help. But the browser you're using will also have a big part in it's performance. I suggest using Chrome and using Dev Tools to profile the javascript and view it's timeline. CSS3 transitions will look much better if you could use a fallback to `slideToggle` when it's not available.

Comment: It would also help to set up a fiddle where you can reproduce the issue.

Comment: I've actually just identified that it's the "blur-logo" class I was attempting to add to notClicked that was slowing it down. I'm using -webkit-filter:blur(3px) in CSS and while my SVG filter code is working in Firefox, the -webkit-filter is slowing down Chrome. Does anyone have any ideas about how to replace -webkit-filter for a blur effect in Chrome?

Comment: Another update: The problem was actually my CSS. I changed the blur to affect ".blur-logo img" instead of just ".blur-logo" and it works smoothly now. Thanks anyway!